# localStorage.setitem и метод filter()

Tags: jquery

У меня есть 2 ссылки и 2 блока.

```
<a class="test" href="/projects/#Webdesign" data-category="Webdesign">Webdesign</a>
<a class="test" href="/projects/#Mobile" data-category="Mobile">Mobile</a>
<div id='Mobile' class="project-banner">mobile block</div>
<div id='Webdesign' class="project-banner">webdesign block</div>
```

При клике на ссылку `.test`, я записываю в localStorage элемент, который хочу отфильтровать по совпадению `target` на id блока.

```
$('.test').click(function () {
const target = this.hash;
console.log(target); //#Mobile

localStorage.setItem('project', $(".project-banner").hide().filter(target).show());
});

if (localStorage.getItem('project') !== null) {
    setItem('project', $(".project-banner").hide().filter(target).show());
}
```

Но проблема в том, что либо не срабатывает метод filter() в localStorage, или в логике моего кода что-то неверно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Корректный код:

```
    $('.test').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const target = this.hash;
        console.log(target); //#Mobile

        localStorage.setItem('project', target);
        $(".project-banner").hide().filter(target).show();
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem('project') !== null) {
        $(".project-banner").hide().filter(localStorage.getItem('project')).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что `localStorage` принимает лишь строку, а ты пытаешься положить непонятые действия.

Попробуй следующий код:

```
$('.test').click(function () {
    const target = this.hash;
    console.log(target); //#Mobile
    localStorage.setItem('project', target);
    )};

if (localStorage.getItem('project') !== null) {
    $(".project-banner").hide().filter(target).show();
    setItem('project', target);
}
```